# Selecting "Skip" when reviewing

Tags: support, review

I want to be sure I understand what the options mean when reviewing a submission. I'm usually faced with choosing "Approve", "Reject", or "Skip" (among others). When can "Skip" be correctly used? I've occasionally chosen "Skip" if I start reviewing a question but find that the changes are rather long and I can't spend too much time on it -- am I making a grievous mistake by selecting "Skip" to back out of the review?

I was thinking this would just put the question back in the review queue, but am I mistakenly approving the question by doing this? Now I'm worried...

Comment: "Skip" is exactly what you should do if you don't know whether to approve or reject. It doesn't matter why you don't know, if you aren't sure, "Skip" to the next review item.

Comment: Okay, great--I'm quite relieved to hear that. Thanks!

Comment: [Related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12633/is-it-rude-to-skip-most-edits); it's better to skip than to approve / reject a choice without carefully considering it, IMHO.